# React doesnt update state immidiately after dropdown selected

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have some update state problems when the dropdown is selected.

The useEffect doesnt update the state immidiately when its selected.

I want my listngs array updated immidiately whenever the selected filter changes.

Thanks

Code

```
const dropdowns = [
    { icon: '', title: 'Top ratings', color: 'warning' },
    { icon: '', title: 'Worst ratings', color: 'warning' },
]
  
const [selectedFilter, setSelectedFilter] = useState("")
  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedFilter === 0) {
      var sorted = listings.sort((a, b) => { return b.rating - a.rating })
      setListings(sorted)
      console.log(listings)
    } else {
      var sorted = listings.sort((a, b) => { return a.rating - b.rating })
      setListings(sorted)
      console.log(listings)
    }
  }, [selectedFilter])



<Dropdown.Menu className='w-100'>
     {dropdowns.map(({ icon, title }, indx) => (
      <Dropdown.Item
       key={indx}
       as='button'
       eventKey={title}
       onClick={() => {
       setSelectedFilter(indx)
       }}>
      <i className={`${icon} fs-lg opacity-60 me-2`}></i>
      {title}
      </Dropdown.Item>
      ))}
  </Dropdown.Menu>
```

Comment: Seems like a redundant effect to me. Try moving the logic of the effect to the onClick handler

Comment: no luck still same tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably will find it useful to read through the ["You might not need an effect"](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect), in particular the ["Updating state based on props or state"](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#updating-state-based-on-props-or-state) section.

Ultimately you don't need an effect to compute derived data, you should just do that directly in render.

```js
const dropdowns = [
    { icon: '', title: 'Top ratings', color: 'warning' },
    { icon: '', title: 'Worst ratings', color: 'warning' },
]

const [selectedFilter, setSelectedFilter] = useState("")

const sortedListings = selectedFilter === 0 ?
  [...listings].sort((a, b) => b.rating - a.rating) : 
  [...listings].sort((a, b) => a.rating - b.rating);

<Dropdown.Menu className='w-100'>
     {dropdowns.map(({ icon, title }, indx) => (
      <Dropdown.Item
       key={indx}
       as='button'
       eventKey={title}
       onClick={() => {
       setSelectedFilter(indx)
       }}>
      <i className={`${icon} fs-lg opacity-60 me-2`}></i>
      {title}
      </Dropdown.Item>
      ))}
  </Dropdown.Menu>
```

The other thing worth noting is in your `useEffect` you're mutating `listings` which is most likely not desirable; instead you should clone the array then sort (hence `[...listings].sort()` rather than `listings.sort()`).

Comment: Aside from that, it's hard to know what other issues you might be experiencing without knowing about the implementation of your Dropdown menu.

Comment: Thanks your solution works. I was always having problem with the useEffect + dropdowns i will use your approach later on :)